# Broccoli.js and Ember-cli, Long compile times with Less

Tags: ember-cli, broccolijs

When compiling with Ember-cli, broccoli, broccoli-less-single, my compile times are extremely long. I am using a template with bootstrap3 and all the dependent less files. The number of less files is admittedly excessive, but the compile times are 20+ secs.

It is recompiling the less files on every save which seems excessive as the less files are not the ones that I am editing. How do I go about trouble shooting this issue?

Thanks for insight on this. It's also a known issue apparently.https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/issues/538